# CompletableFuture on Single core machine

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, completable-future

I am having Kafka consumer production application which consumes a message and splits it in 3 parts and invoke two Rest API and one SOAP WS. Currently these are invoked serially one after the another, they are independent of each other in nature and should be in async ideally.

Also the Kafka consumer is deployed on Azure Small VM having 1 core, link for same [Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-sizes-specs).

I am planning to use `CompletableFuture`'s `supplyAsync()`, but for this I can go for one the below mentioned two options

1. Use custom `Threadpool` of size 3 OR
2. Use `forkjoin` pool

Since I have a single core machine, which one should be pick and why? Also Is `CompletableFuture` is applicable for single core machine?

Comment: Sure, you can use `CompletableFuture`; Java's concurrency is as high level as anything else and abstracts from the actual machine it's running on. Meaning, even if it can actually process in parallel, the JVM will either schedule its tasks itself or just handle it as seems fit - which might be sequential, but that will also be the case for a custom thread or a forkjoin pool.

Comment: Weirdly, the behavior of `CompletableFuture` [is specified as](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) “*All* async *methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task).*” So on a single core machine you might get *more* parallelism, at least from the number of threads perspective. So using an explicit executor is recommended. A fork/join pool *is* a thread pool.

Comment: @Holger In a single core machine , isn't the fork join common pool will have a single core(Runtime.getAvailableProcessors() will return 1) that means only a single thread will be executed at a time? If Yes then using CompleteableFuture doesn't make any sense.

Comment: As the documentation says, when the common pool has a parallelism of less than two, the `CompletableFuture` doesn’t use the common pool but creates a new thread for every task. You can take this literally; it really does `new Thread(…)` then, without using any executor service. That’s why I recommend using an explicit executor with a sensible configuration in this scenario. It can be an ordinary thread pool or a custom fork/join pool with an explicitly specified parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concurrency on single-threaded cpu without any problem, though it will benefit only structure of your program, not performance.

Kafka provides it own shim for `CompletableFuture` [1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) type - `KafkaFuture`[2](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/KafkaFuture.html), you may want to use this instead.